# Too long loading data from DB (laravel, vuejs)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am doing spa on laravel and vue js. There is a page with a list of conferences, and when I go to the page with a list, the data is loaded via api for a very long time, 5-10 seconds pass before the full list appears. Maybe someone knows what is the reason? I can provide all necessary code.

Comment: It depends on many things like: api codes quality, api server response time, quantity of columns and etc... so you probably should search for reason in api side.

Comment: If you have many relationships in your data, try eager loading https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: @MartinAmu i tried to put my web-site on real server and there it works faster. Maybe some problems in my local server settings?

Comment: Try fetch data from api using postman and check response time after that will be clear that where you should search for the issue.

Comment: @MartinAmu i tried. It no longer than 1 sec

Comment: @MartinAmu i tried again just now . It 2.47

Comment: In my case i'm using varnish cache at my side and laravel cache. I think that problem is not at your side. You can improve performance of your DB, use cache system, use reverse proxy and eager loading if you receive bunch of data from api server but it works if api server works stable and in good condition.